# What is the difference between a library file and a header file or are they synonymous?

Tags: c, header, libraries

`#include "stdio.h"` 

`#include "file_created_by_me.h"`

---

In the first include there is a library file, in the second include there is a header file, or both can be called as libraries or headers because library and header are synonymous?

Comment: Basically libraries contain pre-generated, pre-compiled, code and object definitions. Header files contain information (for the compiler and programmer) about what is in the library.

Comment: The form `#include <stdio.h>` is often used for standard library headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are header files.

The first header file provides declarations of some of the functions provided by the C standard library. Therefore, one could say that it is part of the C standard library.

The second header file probably provides declarations of functions that are defined in other parts of your program. Therefore, it is not part of a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)).

A library generally provides header files so that you can `#include` them in your program, so that the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) has the necessary function declarations in order to call the functions in the library. However, the main part of the library, which consists of the actual function definitions, is not imported by the compiler, but rather by the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that header files contains (as said above) some function declarations, library files contains execution code of this functions.
Simple example:
myfunc.h - header file

```
#ifndef MYFUNC_H
#define MY_FUNC_H 1

extern void myfunc(void);

#endif /* MYFUNC_H */
```

myfunc.c - definition of function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myfunc.h"

void myfunc(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

This compiles by example with gcc by this way:

```
gcc -Wall -c myfunc.c
```

and produced file is myfunc.o - this is oure library
And main program:

```
#include "myfunc.h"

int main(void) {
    myfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it:

```
gcc -Wall main.c myfunc.o
```

and run:

```
a.exe
```

in Windows or

```
./a.out
```

in *NIX systems...